# Unity - HDRI Skybox used as lightsource for eye adaptation/tone mapping

Tags: unity-game-engine, skybox, hdr

I am currently trying to create a scene in Unity which should feature an eyeadaptation/tonemapping system, so whenever my camera is watching on a brighter/darker area it should adjust the exposure value of the HDR Image correctly. Unfortunately there is no visible impact on the 'main camera'.

---

My scene consists of a cubemap skybox for which a hdr image is used, a camera to which an post processing behavior from the Asset 'Post Processing Stack' ([Link](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/post-processing-stack-83912)) is attached and a standard cube ([Scene](https://www.dropbox.com/s/imj6kzgsdtngc6u/maincam_scene.JPG?dl=0)). 
The light source in the HDR Image is already recognized correctly as seen in the 'Look Dev' within Unity ([Skybox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gselg0wsudqhv10/skybox.JPG?dl=0)).
Nevertheless I cannot see any effect on my play-scene of the eye-adaptation setting or the tone-mapping option in the 'post process behavior script' ([Script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sspbh529l8u53bw/postprocessbehaviour.JPG?dl=0)) when I rotate the camera to different directions. Only the cube seems to be shaded correctly by the 'sun' occurring in the skybox and rotating the cube will also change its shadows.

For the settings within the project I have followed several tutorials and I have already experimented with them, but without success.
 For example I have set the 'colorspace' to 'linear', the 'rendering path' to 'deferred' and the 'pixel light count' to '20'. I have also adjusted the lighting settings to these [Settings](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jq9sfumureeat90/lighting.JPG?dl=0).

Is there any solution to this problem of mine?
Thank you.